# Color managements problem

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, color-management

I used to adding high color contrast by color management panel in my rendering. However, recently, I find out that the render viewport won't change by the influence of color management. What does the problem happen on my Blender settings? The output images seem normal with the different color setting but not in render viewport.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are showing are the *Output Properties* which are used when you render an animation for example and save the file. They are set to *Override* so that they replace the original scene's *Color Management* settings. The *3D Viewport* uses the settings in the *Render Properties* tab:

[image: render props]

To change the *Color Management* in the viewport, go there. And if you want the rendered images to look the same like the viewport, set the look you want in the viewport's settings and for the *Output Properties* instead of setting them individually with *Override*, switch back to the default *Follow Scene* (which means it uses the color management you have set for the scene for the saved files):

[image: output props]